# Very Annoying Chat Defect

Tags: bug, chat

If you are using Chrome and:

1. your resolution is 1366x768
2. Your window is maximized
3. A link is the last word of the last line of the message

Then, if you attempt to click on the the link is covered by the little "flag\star" hover window, thereby making the link **unclickable**.

Please Fix.

[image]